# where to specify S3 file locations when submitting pig program via AWS CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, apache-pig, aws-cli, amazon-emr

I'm creating a cluster and submitting a Pig step via AWS CLI.  Both the PIG script and the input file to the script are stored in an S3 bucket.

**example** Pig script:

```
REGISTER file:/usr/lib/pig/lib/piggybank.jar;
DEFINE XPath org.apache.pig.piggybank.evaluation.xml.XPath();
A = LOAD 's3://my-group/myfolder/somedata.xml' USING org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.XMLLoader('item') AS (x:chararray);
B = FOREACH A GENERATE XPath(x, 'detail');
STORE B INTO 's3://my-group/myfolder/somedetails';
```

**example** CLI:

```
aws emr create-cluster \
--steps Type=PIG,Name='Pig program',ActionOnFailure=CONTINUE, \
Args=[-f,s3://my-group/myfolder/some_script.pig, \
-p,INPUT=s3://my-group/myfolder,-p,OUTPUT=s3://my-group/myfolder] \
--applications Name=Pig --enable-debugging \
--log-uri s3://my-group/myfolder --release-label emr-5.2.0 \
--instance-groups \
InstanceGroupType=MASTER,InstanceCount=1,InstanceType=m3.2xlarge \
InstanceGroupType=CORE,InstanceCount=5,InstanceType=c1.medium \
--name "Test cluster" --ec2-attributes KeyName=ClusterKeyPair
```

which seems to be working (at least hasn't failed)...

but is it necessary for the `s3://my-group/myfolder` be specified in both locations?  If not what is the preferred way to write this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that within the Pig script, instead of hard-coding the locations I can use EMR Job Flow Parameters `$INPUT` and `$OUTPUT`, as in:

```
A = LOAD '$INPUT' USING org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.XMLLoader('item') AS (x:chararray);
B = FOREACH A GENERATE XPath(x, 'detail');
STORE B INTO '$OUTPUT';
```

Source: [Programming Elastic Mapreduce, ch. 4](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/programming-elastic-mapreduce/9781449364038/ch04.html)